# Network filtering with libvirt + xen + bridge + nat?

Tags: xen, libvirt

How can I properly add basic network filters (clean-traffic or, at least, ip-spoofing prevention) to XEN (xend) guests managed by libvirt?

Or, in particular, can I manually execute libvirt's nwfilters from a script (for given parameters)?

I am using libvirt's network to create the bridge (`default`, bridge `virbr0`), but, apparently, the xen's `vif-bridge` script is used to initialize the virtualized system's networking, and libvirt drops `nwfilter` definitions in domain's xml (probably because it is converted to xen's native config).

Comment: I've run into the same problem – did you find any solution?

Comment: No, it appears that the only solution is to write the iptables/ebtables security filtering manually.

Comment: Which XEN-version and which linux distribution/version?

Comment: Debian stable, i.e. xen 4.1.4, libvirt 0.9.12.

Comment: I should note, what I was hoping for is a way to invoke libvirt's filter addition/removal/reconfigure from the commandline; there doesn't seem to be a way, but it is also _possible_ that someone familiar with libvirt's innards could implement that relatively easily.

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. I've spent the last hour trying to get libvirt nwfilter stuff working, figuring that since it was all iptables stuff, it would just work despite Xen being second-class. Good to know it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

I've also looked into that subject. Here is what Xen 4.x can offer, although it is not well documented and illustrated with sample scripts.

[xend-config.sxp - Xen daemon configuration file](http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.2-testing/man/xend-config.sxp.5.html)

> `vif-script`
>   The name of the script in /etc/xen/scripts that will be run to setup a virtual interface when it is created or destroyed. This needs to (in general) work in unison with the network-script.

You may override global `vif-script` by using `script` keyword inside a `vif` option value of any guest configuration.

[XL Network Configuration](http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/4.2-testing/misc/xl-network-configuration.html)

> `script`
>   Specifies the hotplug script to run to configure this device (e.g. to add it to the relevant bridge). Defaults to XEN_SCRIPT_DIR/vif-bridge but can be set to any script. Some example scripts are installed in XEN_SCRIPT_DIR.

For most Linux systems substitute XEN_SCRIPT_DIR with `/etc/xen/scripts`.

There is also at least one more specific solution in the following Xen-users mailing list discussion: [preventing Hwaddr spoofing on bridge](http://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2007-11/msg00657.html)